# syntax highlight problem in gvim 7.3

Tags: vim, gvim

I upgraded my ubuntu to 11.04 and my gvim got all messed up. I am basically starting from scratch and need some help.  [Upon recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/281860/my-gvim-settings-are-all-messed-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-04), I am starting to move everything related to vim (plugins and vimrc) into `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`

```
after
autoload
colors
doc
ftpplugin
gvimrc (file)
nerdtree
plugin
snippets
syntax
vimrc (file)
vimrc.dpkg-old (file)
vimrc.tiny (file)
```

I also have a .vimrc file in `/home/laptop/.vimrc` This file actually contains the settings/mappings that I've added

`:set runtimepath` fetches:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/vimfiles, 
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/vimfiles/after,
~/.vim/after
```

I have no folder like the one mentioned above `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/vimfiles`

**Questions:**
Why are there two vimrc's? should I swap contents of `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/vimrc` with `/home/laptop/.vimrc`?

**Errors**

```
Error detected while processing /home/laptop/.vimrc
line 6
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

Line 6 is:

```
syntax on
```

my `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax` originally only contained `snippet.vim`, however, the `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax` folder contained many many other files. like `gdb.vim, jsp.vim, groovy.vim, libao.vim...etc (more than 60 files)`

so I copied all of those files to `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax` but still error is there

how can I get back my syntax highlighting?

**Update**

- had vim73_backup and now changed it back to `/user/share/vim/vim73`
- `:set rtp?` does not have vim73 (as shown above)
- `:echo $VIM $VIMRUNTIME` shows `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles /usr/share/vim/vimfiles` since this is wrong..how do I get vim73 here?

Comment: Thanks for getting that information. Your 'runtimepath' explains why your `syntax on` command was not working and why your `sudo ln -s ...` got it working. `:help $VIMRUNTIME` explains why it is set to the same as $VIM. `:help $VIM` explains how $VIM is set, but I can't tell from the information we've seen so far how it got set to `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`. That's wrong. Given the other information you've given, your $VIM should be `/usr/share/vim`. Did you set $VIM yourself? What happens if you start vim as `VIM= vim -u NONE` then execute `:echo $VIM`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no reason to copy the files in /usr/share/vim/vim73 anywhere else. Your gvim already knows about those files and sources them when needed. You should remove from /usr/share/vim/vimfiles any files you copied there unchanged from /usr/share/vim/vim73.
- Vim looks for runtime files (e.g., syntax files) in several places. These places are specified in the 'runtimepath' ('rtp' for short) option. You can read more about this in
  `:help rtp`
  You can see the current value of 'rtp' by executing
  `:set rtp?`
  As you can see from that, Vim already looks in ~/.vim, /usr/share/vim/vimfiles and a few other places as well as /usr/share/vim/vim73.
- You need to find out why you are getting that error message at line 6 because the `:syntax on` command should not be looking for syntax/syntax.vim in /usr/share/vim/. That suggests that your $VIM and/or $VIMRUNTIME variables are messed up. Try executing
  `:echo $VIM $VIMRUNTIME`
  The result should be `/usr/share/vim /usr/share/vim/vim73`.
- In addition to what benizi wrote (as I was writing this), you can find out about the various vimrcs on your system by reading
  `:help vimrc`
  You can also see where your vim is looking for its vimrcs by executing
  `:version`
  and you can see what files your vim has actually sourced by executing
  `:scriptnames`

All of that is probably not enough to completely fix your installation, but it will be a good start towards finding out what's broken and understanding where various files should go. We can go from there to get it all working properly.

Comment: please see my updates relative to your answer. thanks for working with me on this

Comment: adding following to my .vimrc mad everything dandy.`:let &runtimepath.=',/usr/share/vim/vim73'
:let $VIMRUNTIME = "/usr/share/vim/vim73"` plus the things you suggested ofcourse

Comment: I looked at your updates and left a comment below them. It makes sense that these changes got it working, but as I wrote above, the fundamental problem is that your $VIM has somehow been set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be misinterpreting the suggestion in the question you linked.

Don't put anything in the globally shared /usr/share/vim/(anything) directories.  As you discovered too late, it may well be overwritten when you update Vim.

Instead, put custom files in directories under a directory called .vim in your home directory.  So, if you had a custom `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/gdb.vim` file, put that in `$HOME/.vim/syntax/gdb.vim`.  If you have a custom colorscheme, put it in `$HOME/.vim/colors/name-of-scheme.vim`.

To directly answer the question you asked, though, here are the purposes of the various `vimrc`s you've mentioned:

```
/home/laptop/:
    .vimrc            - your personal .vimrc (won't be touched on upgrade, etc.)
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/:
     vimrc            - systemwide `vimrc` (affects all users on the system)
     vimrc.dpkg-old   - possibly your pre-upgrade modified version
     vimrc.tiny       - systemwide `vimrc` for the 'tiny' version of Vim
```

Comment: got it. i'll move everything to `~/.vim/` once I have this syntax highlighting issue resolved. any thoughts on that?